# How to set the sag search icon color? now it is coverd by black color

Tags: css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmoWF.png)

This is a text field when it is normal the search icon should me blue.

```
input: {
    color: 'black',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    '&-ms-::placeholder, &-webkit-::placeholder, &::placeholder': {
      color: 'black',
      fontSize: '12px',
      backgroundColor: 'white',
    },
    '& + svg': {
      fill: '#00a1af',
    },
}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing your CSS, but can you please provide the relevant HTML as well? It's rather difficult to answer this question without being able to see how your existing page is rendered. It would help if you could update your question to list **all** relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If your HTML is generated server-side, could you please post the **output**. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Comment: We need more information. This isn't true css. Not sure what your using to compile this to actual css but it would be nice if you told us. Also include the relevant html as well, please.

Comment: `<div className={classNames([classes.wrapper, disabled ? classes.disabled : undefined,])}>
    <input
      className={classNames([
        classes.input,
        disabled ? classes.disabled : undefined,
      ])}
      placeholder={placeholder}
      type="text"
      value={value}
      disabled={disabled}
    />
    <Icon size={16} icon="search" className={classes.icon} />
  </div>`